# QGIS OpenGeo Explorer plugin and https geoserver

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, boundless-suite

Is there a way to connect to a secure geoserver with OpenGeo Explorer plugin in QGIS?  When I connect to geosever with a secure protocol I get the error `Warning: Cannot connect using the provided certificate/key values`  and the site does not load in the catalog list and when I try to connect via the ip or hostname on my vpn with `x.x.x.x/geoserver` or `hostname/geoserver` it connects and I see it in the catalog  but I get an error in QGIS.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\geoserverexplorer\gui\explorer.py", line 101, in run
    command(*params)
  File "C:/Users/xxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\geoserverexplorer\gui\gsexploreritems.py", line 345, in populate
    layerItem.populate()
  File "C:/Users/xxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\geoserverexplorer\gui\gsexploreritems.py", line 714, in populate
    if layer.default_style is not None:
  File "C:\Users\xxx\.qgis2\python\plugins\geoserverexplorer\ext-libs\gsconfig-1.0.6-py2.7.egg\geoserver\layer.py", line 127, in _get_default_style
    return self._resolve_style(element) if element is not None else None
  File "C:\Users\xxx\.qgis2\python\plugins\geoserverexplorer\ext-libs\gsconfig-1.0.6-py2.7.egg\geoserver\layer.py", line 135, in _resolve_style
    return self.catalog.get_style_by_url(style_workspace_url)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\.qgis2\python\plugins\geoserverexplorer\ext-libs\gsconfig-1.0.6-py2.7.egg\geoserver\catalog.py", line 797, in get_style_by_url
    dom = self.get_xml(style_workspace_url)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\.qgis2\python\plugins\geoserverexplorer\ext-libs\gsconfig-1.0.6-py2.7.egg\geoserver\catalog.py", line 211, in get_xml
    response, content = self.http.request(rest_url)
  File "C:/Users/xxx/.qgis2/python/plugins\geoserverexplorer\geoserver\retry.py", line 19, in decorator
    raise e
SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:340: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

How do I get QGIS and the plugin to accept a cert?

Comment: For those using old versions, like me...: GeoServer 2.6.2 on plain HTTP works with QGIS 2.12.2.1 32 bits. The 64 bits version threw the above error to me. Earlier I got the same error with more recent 64 bits versions of QGIS, but I have not tried the 32 bit versions of those more recent QGIS versions.

Comment: Update on my earlier comment: in QGIS 2.12.2.1, 32 bits, GeoServer Explorer 0.1.1 nicely lists all layers of a GeoServer 2.6.2 server, but dragging them onto a QGIS project throws "Layer is not valid". However, selecting a layer using a server connection as defined in Menu Layer, Add Layer, WFS Layer works just fine. And meanwhile I also tried QGIS 2.16.3, 32 bits. But for that, GeoServer Explorer 0.5, using a HTTP URL, throws me `[Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`. In short: time to upgrade our GeoServer and tooling :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don;t need to give QGIS the cert.  In the Catalog Definition click the tab `Configurations`  then `Add`  I did basic auth with a username and password and entered a secure protocol url in the resource and it worked

Its not greatly documented but there is a refrence to secure servers in the user docs https://github.com/boundlessgeo/qgis-geoserver-plugin/blob/master/docs/source/intro.rst

[image]
[image]